# Retrieve name of fields of a JSONObject - Java

Tags: java, json

I have to retrieve all name of fields of `JSONObject`in Java. 
For example, this is a JSON:

```
{
"name" : {
        "first" : "John",
        "last" : "McCarthy"
    },
"birth" : ISODate("1927-09-04T04:00:00.000Z"),
"death" : ISODate("2011-12-24T05:00:00.000Z"),
"contribs" : [ 
        "Lisp", 
        "Artificial Intelligence", 
        "ALGOL"
    ]
}
```

This JSON object is just an example, I can't know what a JSONObject contains since I import it. I don't have any information about the name of fields to use Gson/Jackson to deserialization.

Suppose I have a `JSONObject myDocJson` that contains the previous JSON Object, I use an iterator:

```
Iterator<?> keys = myDocJson.keySet().iterator();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
System.out.println(keys.next());
}
```

And as a result I get:

```
name
birth
death
contribs
```

But for example I don't have `name.first` and `name.last`. So this iterator does not work with innested Object.

Answer (score 3):

You are only printing the keys.

To get the values, try

```
JSONObject object = null; // your json object
for (Object key : object.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + "=" + object.get(key)); // to get the value
}
```

**EDIT**

And for the objects inside of your JSONObject try

```
JSONObject object = null; // your json object
for (Object key : object.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + "=" + object.get(key)); // to get the value
    for (Object subKey : ((JSONObject) object.get(key)).keySet()) {
        System.out.println(subKey + "=" + object.get(subKey));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need values. I need just the name of keys,

Comment: its not taking the order of json file...for example, if the file key order is name,occupation,city,state...it is taking as "ocuupation,city,state,name"...Any idea about the order?

Comment: i'd strongly recommend using gson instead of jsonsimple... but I don't think you can rely on an order.